# What is the radius of convergence of $\sum_{k\geq 0}3^{k^2}x^{k^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

What is the radius of convergence of $\sum_{k\geq 0}3^{k^2}x^{k^2}$.

**MY TRIAL**
Using Cauchy's root test $$\limsup\limits_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{3^{k^2}}=\limsup\limits_{k\to\infty}3^k=\infty.$$

So, radius of convergence is $0.$ Kindly check, I'm I right?

Comment: The root should be the $k^2$ root, not the $k$ root, because the power of $x$ is $k^2$. So you need $\sqrt[k^2]{3^{k^2}} = 3$, so the $\lim sup$ is $3$. So the convergence radius is $1/3$.

Comment: @Mriganka Basu Roy Chowdhury: Hmm? Wow, that's true!

Comment: @Mriganka Basu Roy Chowdhury: Thanks a lot!